# Qt - QStackedLayout setCurrentIndex displays blank window instead of widget

Tags: qt

I just started learning Qt a couple days ago to make a game, and I'm trying to figure out how to make layouts work.

What I want is a Window using QStackedLayout with 2 widgets inside: StartScreen and GameScreen. StartScreen is shown on top on program run. A button in StartScren is connected to a function inside Window, and Window will call setCurrentIndex to change the widget on top to GameScreen.

What happens right now is that when I click on the button, the view changes to a blank window. I've tried hardcoding to setCurrentIndex(0), which does nothing, setCurrentIndex(1), which is what GameScreen should be and displays the same blank window, and setCurrentIndex(2), which is out of index bounds but still does nothing. So the connection is going through, but I don't understand why a blank window will show up instead of the button I have on GameScreen.

If someone can explain to me what concept I missed and how to fix it, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Here is window.cpp:

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  resize(640, 480);

  layout = new QStackedLayout;

  createStartScreen();
  createGameScreen();
  setLayout(layout);

  show();

};

void Window::createStartScreen(){

  start = new StartScreen();

  layout->addWidget(start);

  start->setWindow(this);

}

void Window::playGame(){

  layout->setCurrentIndex(layout->indexOf(game));

}

void Window::createGameScreen(){

  game = new GameScreen();

  layout->addWidget(game);
}
```

startscreen.cpp:

```
StartScreen::StartScreen(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  newGameButton = new QPushButton("New Game", this);
  newGameButton->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(260, 300), QSize(120,40)));

  quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit", this);
  quitButton->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(260, 360), QSize(120,40)));

  connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));

};

void StartScreen::setWindow(Window *w){

  connect(newGameButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), w, SLOT(playGame()));

}
```

gamescreen.cpp:

```
GameScreen::GameScreen(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
  button = new QPushButton("Hi");
  button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(260, 260), QSize(120,40)));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't call show on button. But you should rather use a layout to handle it.

e.g.:

```
GameScreen::GameScreen(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    button = new QPushButton(tr("Hi"));
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(button);
};
```

button will have a size adapted to its text and will be cleaned positioned in GameScreen.

On a side note, you should rather add a signal to StartScreen to request a new game and do the connection in Window. That way you won't have a tight coupling between StartScreen and Window.

Comment: I found the problem while implementing your suggestion, I didn't add "this" to the parameter inside QPushButton. I also tried using button -> show() but it caused the button to appear in a separate window.

Your feedback on the coupling is really valuable, I shall change that with my program.

Thank you for your answer!